# Metro App Style Combobox NOT items

Tags: combobox, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

How do I style a Metro App `ComboBox`, but not the `ComboBoxItems`?

Specifically, I would like to style the `ToggleButton` in the `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `ComboBox` style on which I changed the default `DropDownGlyph` with a red ellipse:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <CarouselPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedHighlightThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" ContentTranslationOffset="0" ContentTargetName="ScrollViewer" ClosedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownClosedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" ContentTranslationOffset="40" ContentTranslationDirection="{Binding TemplateSettings.SelectedItemDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" ContentTargetName="ScrollViewer" ClosedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownClosedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedHighlightThemeBrush}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Highlight" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBoxSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                            <!-- NEW -->
                            <!-- I putted the ellipse inside a contentcontrol to not break the animations that use properties like Foreground,
                            if you do not need it, just remove them -->
                            <ContentControl x:Name="DropDownGlyph" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Fill="Red" />
                            </ContentControl>
                            <!-- /NEW -->

                            <!-- ORIGINAL
                            <TextBlock x:Name="DropDownGlyph" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowForegroundThemeBrush}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}" FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,0,6,4" Text="&#xE011;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                /ORIGINAL
                            -->

                            <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```